# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka "errorChannel" header

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We're currently using the Spring Cloud Stream to provide a `SubscribableChannel` for input and a `MessageChannel` for output, and we use Spring Integration to provide business logic between the two Kafka topics. In other Spring Integration applications, we have used the `errorChannel` header to dynamically provide the error handling channel (for example, changing the error channel when a certain change has occurred that will need to be rolled back on an error).

However, the input channel provided by Spring Cloud Stream does not appear to honor the `errorChannel` header. Is there a way to enable this?

Example code (please excuse typos--hand copied from another machine)

```
public interface TestStreams {
     @Input
    SubscribableChannel input();

    @Output
    MessageChannel output();
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(TestSTreams.class)
public class TestService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestProcessorMicroservice.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow buildProcessingFlow(TestStreams streams, TransformerThatThrowsException transformer) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(streams.input())
                .enrichHeaders(ImmutableMap.of(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "errorChannel")
                .transform(transformer)
                .channel(streams.output())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow buildErrorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
            .handle(new MyErrorHandler())
            .get();
    }
}
```

The code above runs properly, but when the transformer throws an exception, the error is handled by `org.springframework.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler` instead of being routed to `errorChannel` and ultimately being handled by `MyErrorHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to work that way because an exception is thrown to the `KafkaListenerContainer` with the mentioned `LoggingErrorHandler` by default. The `errorChannel` just doesn't have any value in that context. Because there is no Spring Integration initiator of the flow.

If you want to handle `.transform(transformer)` errors, you can consider to use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with its `failureChannel` functionality.

See its JavaDocs and [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain) for more info.

To add such an `Advice` into the flow, you need to add one more lambda argument for that `transform()`. For example:

```
.transform(transformer, e -> e.advice(myExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice())
```

Comment: Hrm... if I'm reading correctly, that only applies to a single transformer. Our actual use cases have many transformers/service activators (I just used a simplified example for readability). Is there any way to apply advice to the entire flow? Or perhaps to change the handler used by `KafkaListenerContainer`?

Comment: You can wrap some sub-flow with a `.gateway()` and its `errorChannel()` is going to be applied to the whole sub-flow.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks!